# PostgreSQL and Tools for Analyzing Performance Cost For Frequent Large Inserts

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, azure, performance

I am designing an Ingest process that inserts many rows into several tables. We are running PostgreSQL on Azure's PostgreSQL Flexible server. It currently appears that write/insertion speed to this server is the bottleneck for increasing payload throughput (processing JSON payloads with a REST API through a Queue with a target completion rate of 100 payloads/per minute).

Are there any PostgreSQL / database tools for analyzing INSERT performance similar to how we can analyze SELECT performance with EXPLAIN ANALYZE? I know that Indexes and Foreign Keys can have an impact to INSERT speed. I imagine the actual column types for each table, and the length of inserted strings could also have an impact.

Here are some measured insert speeds for 2 of the larger tables. We are using psycopg2 package in Python to execute_values in bulk "INSERT INTO ... VALUES":

Resource table, better performance & less sensitivity to row count.

```
"Resource Insert: 35 ms, 120 rows, 0.2916666666666667 ms/row" # 1 Slide model
"Resource Insert: 36 ms, 120 rows, 0.3 ms/row"
"Resource Insert: 47 ms, 120 rows, 0.39166666666666666 ms/row"
"Resource Insert: 99 ms, 381 rows, 0.25984251968503935 ms/row" # 10 Slides
"Resource Insert: 97 ms, 381 rows, 0.2545931758530184 ms/row"
"Resource Insert: 117 ms, 381 rows, 0.30708661417322836 ms/row"
"Resource Insert: 654 ms, 2991 rows, 0.21865596790371114 ms/row" # 100 Slides
"Resource Insert: 683 ms, 2991 rows, 0.22835172183216315 ms/row"
"Resource Insert: 665 ms, 2991 rows, 0.2223336676696757 ms/row"
"Resource Insert: 5604 ms, 29091 rows, 0.19263689800969372 ms/row" # 1000 Slides
"Resource Insert: 5498 ms, 29091 rows, 0.1889931593963769 ms/row"
"Resource Insert: 5021 ms, 29091 rows, 0.17259633563645113 ms/row"
"Resource Insert: 4743 ms, 29091 rows, 0.16304011549963907 ms/row"
"Resource Insert: 8428 ms, 29091 rows, 0.2897115946512667 ms/row"
"Resource Insert: 7788 ms, 29091 rows, 0.26771166340105185 ms/row"
"Resource Insert: 7367 ms, 29091 rows, 0.25323983362551994 ms/row"
```

Resource Value table, insert performance worse & scales poorly with higher row counts

```
"Resource Val Insert: 378 ms, 113 rows, 3.3451327433628317 ms/row" ~ 1 Slide + Acc,Pat,Cli,TestOrder,Block
"Resource Val Insert: 365 ms, 113 rows, 3.230088495575221 ms/row" 
"Resource Val Insert: 356 ms, 113 rows, 3.150442477876106 ms/row"
"Resource Val Insert: 422 ms, 113 rows, 3.734513274336283 ms/row"
"Resource Val Insert: 439 ms, 113 rows, 3.8849557522123894 ms/row"
"Resource Val Insert: 354 ms, 113 rows, 3.1327433628318584 ms/row"
"Resource Val Insert: 1498 ms, 365 rows, 4.104109589041096 ms/row" # 10 Slides
"Resource Val Insert: 1509 ms, 365 rows, 4.134246575342465 ms/row"
"Resource Val Insert: 1568 ms, 365 rows, 4.295890410958904 ms/row"
"Resource Val Insert: 1607 ms, 365 rows, 4.402739726027397 ms/row"
"Resource Val Insert: 1553 ms, 365 rows, 4.254794520547946 ms/row"
"Resource Val Insert: 14187 ms, 2885 rows, 4.917504332755633 ms/row" # 100 Slides
"Resource Val Insert: 14239 ms, 2885 rows, 4.935528596187175 ms/row"
"Resource Val Insert: 13494 ms, 2885 rows, 4.677296360485268 ms/row"
"Resource Val Insert: 14489 ms, 2885 rows, 5.0221837088388215 ms/row"
"Resource Val Insert: 14044 ms, 2885 rows, 4.867937608318891 ms/row"
"Resource Val Insert: 131665 ms, 28085 rows, 4.688089727612605 ms/row" # 1000 Slides
"Resource Val Insert: 133214 ms, 28085 rows, 4.743243724408047 ms/row"
"Resource Val Insert: 132070 ms, 28085 rows, 4.7025102367812 ms/row"
```

Here is the DDL for the related tables, which likely is a factor: Average Performance Inserts - resource table

```
                                                    Table "public.resource"
      Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |   Default    | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 resource_id       | integer                     |           | not null |              | plain    |              |
 uuid              | uuid                        |           | not null |              | plain    |              |
 name              | character varying           |           |          |              | extended |              |
 url               | character varying           |           |          |              | extended |              |
 desc              | character varying           |           |          |              | extended |              |
 barcode           | character varying           |           |          |              | extended |              |
 barcode_type      | character varying           |           |          |              | extended |              |
 meta              | jsonb                       |           |          |              | extended |              |
 cls               | integer                     |           | not null |              | plain    |              |
 archived          | boolean                     |           | not null |              | plain    |              |
 view_template     | character varying           |           | not null |              | extended |              |
 created_timestamp | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |              | plain    |              |
 updated_timestamp | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |              | plain    |              |
 owner_resource_id | integer                     |           |          |              | plain    |              |
 tenant            | character varying           |           | not null | CURRENT_USER | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "resource_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (resource_id, tenant)
    "_uuid_tenant_uc" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (uuid, tenant)
    "param_group_unique_name" UNIQUE, btree (name) WHERE cls = 600
    "resource_resource_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (resource_id)
    "ix_resource_barcode" btree (barcode)
    "ix_resource_desc" btree ("desc")
    "ix_resource_name" btree (name)
    "ix_resource_uuid" btree (uuid)
    "lab7_role_unique_name" btree (lower(name::text)) WHERE cls = 221 OR cls = 222 OR cls = 220
    "resource_created_timestamp_idx" btree (created_timestamp DESC)
    "resource_updated_timestamp_idx" btree (updated_timestamp DESC)
Check constraints:
    "resource_check" CHECK (resource_id <> owner_resource_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "resource_owner_resource_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (owner_resource_id) REFERENCES resource(resource_id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "address" CONSTRAINT "address_address_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES resource(resource_id)
    # .... and many more references! This is our most basic table that acts sort of like an abstract base class
```

Poorly Performing Table Inserts

```
\d+ resource_val
                                                Table "public.resource_val"
         Column          |       Type        | Collation | Nullable |   Default    | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-------------------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 resource_val_id         | integer           |           | not null |              | plain    |              |
 resource_var_id         | integer           |           |          |              | plain    |              |
 value_group_id          | integer           |           |          |              | plain    |              |
 sort_id                 | integer           |           |          |              | plain    |              |
 value                   | character varying |           |          |              | extended |              |
 expression              | character varying |           |          |              | extended |              |
 dropdown                | jsonb             |           |          |              | extended |              |
 bound_resource_id       | integer           |           |          |              | plain    |              |
 error_msg               | character varying |           |          |              | extended |              |
 dropdown_error_msg      | character varying |           |          |              | extended |              |
 tenant                  | character varying |           | not null | CURRENT_USER | extended |              |
 step_instance_sample_id | integer           |           |          |              | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "resource_val_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (resource_val_id)
    "idx_res_val_hash" hash (value)
    "ix_r_val_bound_resource_id" btree (bound_resource_id)
    "ix_r_val_sis_id" btree (step_instance_sample_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "resource_val_bound_resource_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (bound_resource_id) REFERENCES resource(resource_id)
    "resource_val_resource_val_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (resource_val_id) REFERENCES resource(resource_id)
    "resource_val_resource_var_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (resource_var_id) REFERENCES resource_var(resource_var_id)
    "resource_val_step_instance_sample_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (step_instance_sample_id) REFERENCES step_instance_sample(association_id)
    "resource_val_value_group_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (value_group_id) REFERENCES resource_val_group(id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` does work for INSERT.  It isn't as useful for them as it is for SELECT, but it is still the best starting point you have.  It does at least break out the timing for foreign key constraints separately, although it doesn't break down the index maintenance time.

Your "scales poorly" doesn't ring true to me.  The performance drop is small, and is inconsistent.  Most times for "100 slides" are worse than any time for "1000 slides", for example.  Assuming the presentation is in chronological order, maybe something else is going on as time progresses, like running out of "credits" from your cloud provider or getting the OS cache congested with dirty pages, or the just the indexes growing to the point they can't stay in cache anymore (but that difference would be much larger than you are seeing).  To be convincing you would need to run the tests with more of them, and with batch sizes in random order not in a predictable progression.  And if the difference (over batch size) is real, is it large enough to worry about?

Now inserts do scale poorly, but that is related to the size of the indexes of the table being inserted into, not the size of the batches being inserted.  And when the bad behavior kicks in, it is like falling off a cliff, it is not just a 20% drop in performance.

Usually the best way to investigate this kind of thing, assuming looking at `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` isn't enough, is just to drop some of the constraints/indexes and see what happens.

Comment: I have some more context today.  So I should have started out by giving out some of the current structure/size.  I have already inserted a few million rows in these tables.

 schemaname |                relname                |  reltuples
------------+---------------------------------------+-------------
 public     | resource                              | 4.05148e+07
 public     | resource_val                          | 3.77053e+07
 public     | resource_action                       | 5.71963e+06

Comment: resource --- row count 4.05148e+07
resource_val --- row count 3.77053e+07
The largest inserts tested were 28000 rows at a time for both tables. The insert time per row in resource_val was almost a factor of 10 larger than time for resource table inserts (ms/row calculation).

What I discovered today is that a Hash Index on resource_val.value accounts for the majority of the difference.  The column is varchar and the longest value was 2KB.  We may try a GIN index instead. I was hoping for a Cost for Index work, but sounds like the best tool is trial and error.

Comment: We ended up switching from a Hash Index to a GIN Trigram Index using pg_trgm.  We couldn't use btree on the column due to an unconstrained length that hit the size limit.  We saw a factor of 100 improvement for the table in question going from 4 ms/row to 0.4 ms/row.

We are seeing similar Index driven costs where we have uuid4s indexed in 2 columns on our main table. This seems to cause us to need to touch lots of parts of those btree indexes and inflates IOPS a great deal.